# Firestore: calling collections.get() inside promise()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
if (!stop) {
  // get current user profile
  db.collection('events').get(eventId).then((doc) => {
    doc.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        let temp = doc.data()
        let tempDivisions = []
        temp["id"] = doc.ref.id
        doc.ref.collection('divisions').get().then((docs) => {
          docs.forEach(doc => {
            let temp = doc.data()
            temp["ref"] = doc.ref.path
            tempDivisions.push(temp)
          });
        })
        temp['divisions'] = tempDivisions
        setEvent(temp)
        setStop(true)
        // setLoading(false);
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
        <Redirect to="/page-not-found" />
      }
    })
  })
}
  }, [stop, eventId]);
```

I am curious if this is the properly way to extract nested data from Cloud Firestore.
Data model:
Collection(Events) -> Doc(A) -> Collection(Divisions) -> Docs(B, C, D, ...)

Pretty much I'm looking to get metadata from Doc(A), then get all the sub-collections which contain Docs(B, C, D, ...)

Current Problem: I am able to get meta data for Doc(A) and its subcollections(Divisions), but the front-end on renders metadata of Doc(A). Front-End doesn't RE-RENDER the sub-collections even though. However, react devtools show that subcollections(Divisions) are available in the state.

**EDIT 2:**

```
    const [entries, setEntries] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let active = true
    let temp = []
    if (active) {
      divisions.forEach((division) => {
        let teams = []
        let tempDivision = division
        db.collection(`${division.ref}/teams`).get().then((docs) => {
          docs.forEach((doc, index) => {
            teams.push(doc.data())
          })
          tempDivision['teams'] = teams
        })
        setEntries(oldArray => [...oldArray, temp])
      })
    }
    
    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [divisions]);
```

is there any reason why this is not detecting new array and trigger a new state and render? From what I can see here, it should be updating and re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query `doc.ref.collection('divisions').get()` doesn't do anything to force the current component to re-render.  Simply pushing elements into an array isn't going to tell the component that it needs to render what's in that array.

You're going to have to use a state hook to tell the component to render again with new data, similar to what you're already doing with `setEvent()` and `setStop()`.

Comment: If I do `setDivisions(tempDivisions)` inside `doc.ref.collection('divisions').get()`, will that render again? I originally had this, but it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: If that's a state hook method, then it should cause a re-render using the data you provide.

Comment: thank you so much. I had this setup before and i'm not sure why it was throwing error, I guess this happens when you work late at night haha

Comment: can you take a look at EDIT 2? I'm facing state not re-rendering again. useState hook is being used, I think properly.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it separately.  Stack Overflow only can allow a single question per post.